# Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory caused by "Could not create connection to database server."

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, wildfly

I'm trying to deploy my .war on WildFlt 14.0.1.Final, but i have error that i can't figure out what it means.

I've deployed the JDBC driver and my Datasource binds correctly according to this message in the system output:

```
20:08:54,471 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYJCA0018: Started Driver service with driver-name = mysql
20:08:55,708 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYJCA0001: Bound data source [java:/temproDS]
```

However, when I try to deploy my WAR file I'll get the following error:

```
20:50:37,592 WARN  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 75) HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata : javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000453: Unable to get managed connection for java:/temproDS
20:50:37,593 INFO  [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 75) HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
20:50:37,594 INFO  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.LobCreatorBuilderImpl] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 75) HHH000422: Disabling contextual LOB creation as connection was null
20:50:37,596 INFO  [org.hibernate.envers.boot.internal.EnversServiceImpl] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 75) Envers integration enabled? : true
20:50:37,705 WARN  [org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.strategy.OnePool] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 75) IJ000604: Throwable while attempting to get a new connection: null: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ031084: Unable to create connection
        at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.createLocalManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:345)
        at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.getLocalManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:352)
        at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.createManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:287)
        at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.mcp.SemaphoreConcurrentLinkedDequeManagedConnectionPool.createConnectionEventListener(SemaphoreConcurrentLinkedDequeManagedConnectionPool.java:1326)
        at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.mcp.SemaphoreConcurrentLinkedDequeManagedConnectionPool.getConnection(SemaphoreConcurrentLinkedDequeManagedConnectionPool.java:499)
        at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.AbstractPool.getSimpleConnection(AbstractPool.java:632)
        at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.AbstractPool.getConnection(AbstractPool.java:604)
        at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.AbstractConnectionManager.getManagedConnection(AbstractConnectionManager.java:624)
        at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.tx.TxConnectionManagerImpl.getManagedConnection(TxConnectionManagerImpl.java:440)
        at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.AbstractConnectionManager.allocateConnection(AbstractConnectionManager.java:789)
        at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrapperDataSource.getConnection(WrapperDataSource.java:138)
        at org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources.WildFlyDataSource.getConnection(WildFlyDataSource.java:64)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:180)
        at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jta.internal.DdlTransactionIsolatorJtaImpl.<init>(DdlTransactionIsolatorJtaImpl.java:59)
        at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jta.internal.JtaTransactionCoordinatorBuilderImpl.buildDdlTransactionIsolator(JtaTransactionCoordinatorBuilderImpl.java:46)
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.HibernateSchemaManagementTool.getDdlTransactionIsolator(HibernateSchemaManagementTool.java:175)
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.doMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:94)
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:183)
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:72)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:310)
        at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:467)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:939)
        at org.jboss.as.jpa.hibernate5.TwoPhaseBootstrapImpl.build(TwoPhaseBootstrapImpl.java:44)
        at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:167)
        at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:125)
        at org.wildfly.security.manager.WildFlySecurityManager.doChecked(WildFlySecurityManager.java:650)
        at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:209)
        at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1985)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1487)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1378)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
        at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:485)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server.
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:408)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:918)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:897)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:886)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:860)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2330)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2083)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:806)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:410)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:328)
        at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.createLocalManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:321)
        ... 33 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getServerCharset(ConnectionImpl.java:2997)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendConnectionAttributes(MysqlIO.java:1934)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.proceedHandshakeWithPluggableAuthentication(MysqlIO.java:1863)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1226)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2253)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2284)
        ... 44 more

20:50:37,706 WARN  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 75) SQL Error: 0, SQLState: null
20:50:37,707 ERROR [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 75) javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000453: Unable to get managed connection for java:/temproDS
20:50:37,707 INFO  [org.hibernate.orm.beans] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 75) HHH10005004: Stopping BeanContainer : org.hibernate.resource.beans.container.internal.CdiBeanContainerExtendedAccessImpl@7c7fc083
20:50:37,708 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 75) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.persistenceunit."progettoswam-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war#production": org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.persistenceunit."progettoswam-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war#production": javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: production] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
        at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:195)
        at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:125)
        at org.wildfly.security.manager.WildFlySecurityManager.doChecked(WildFlySecurityManager.java:650)
        at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:209)
        at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1985)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1487)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1378)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
        at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:485)
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: production] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.persistenceException(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1016)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:942)
        at org.jboss.as.jpa.hibernate5.TwoPhaseBootstrapImpl.build(TwoPhaseBootstrapImpl.java:44)
        at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:167)
        ... 9 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution
        at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:47)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:99)
        at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jta.internal.DdlTransactionIsolatorJtaImpl.<init>(DdlTransactionIsolatorJtaImpl.java:62)
        at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jta.internal.JtaTransactionCoordinatorBuilderImpl.buildDdlTransactionIsolator(JtaTransactionCoordinatorBuilderImpl.java:46)
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.HibernateSchemaManagementTool.getDdlTransactionIsolator(HibernateSchemaManagementTool.java:175)
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.doMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:94)
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:183)
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:72)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:310)
        at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:467)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:939)
        ... 11 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000453: Unable to get managed connection for java:/temproDS
        at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrapperDataSource.getConnection(WrapperDataSource.java:146)
        at org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources.WildFlyDataSource.getConnection(WildFlyDataSource.java:64)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:180)
        at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jta.internal.DdlTransactionIsolatorJtaImpl.<init>(DdlTransactionIsolatorJtaImpl.java:59)
        ... 19 more
Caused by: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000453: Unable to get managed connection for java:/temproDS
        at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.AbstractConnectionManager.getManagedConnection(AbstractConnectionManager.java:690)
        at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.tx.TxConnectionManagerImpl.getManagedConnection(TxConnectionManagerImpl.java:440)
        at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.AbstractConnectionManager.allocateConnection(AbstractConnectionManager.java:789)
        at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrapperDataSource.getConnection(WrapperDataSource.java:138)
        ... 23 more
Caused by: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ031084: Unable to create connection
        at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.createLocalManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:345)
        at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.getLocalManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:352)
        at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.createManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:287)
        at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.mcp.SemaphoreConcurrentLinkedDequeManagedConnectionPool.createConnectionEventListener(SemaphoreConcurrentLinkedDequeManagedConnectionPool.java:1326)
        at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.mcp.SemaphoreConcurrentLinkedDequeManagedConnectionPool.getConnection(SemaphoreConcurrentLinkedDequeManagedConnectionPool.java:499)
        at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.AbstractPool.getSimpleConnection(AbstractPool.java:632)
        at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.AbstractPool.getConnection(AbstractPool.java:604)
        at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.AbstractConnectionManager.getManagedConnection(AbstractConnectionManager.java:624)
        ... 26 more
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server.
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:408)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:918)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:897)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:886)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:860)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2330)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2083)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:806)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:410)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:328)
        at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.createLocalManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:321)
        ... 33 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getServerCharset(ConnectionImpl.java:2997)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendConnectionAttributes(MysqlIO.java:1934)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.proceedHandshakeWithPluggableAuthentication(MysqlIO.java:1863)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1226)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2253)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2284)
        ... 44 more

20:50:37,712 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("full-replace-deployment") failed - address: ([]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.persistenceunit.\"progettoswam-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war#production\"" => "javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: production] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: production] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution
    Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000453: Unable to get managed connection for java:/temproDS
    Caused by: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000453: Unable to get managed connection for java:/temproDS
    Caused by: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ031084: Unable to create connection
    Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server.
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException"}}
20:50:37,746 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) WFLYSRV0016: Replaced deployment "progettoswam-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war" with deployment "progettoswam-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war"
20:50:37,747 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) WFLYCTL0183: Service status report
WFLYCTL0186:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.persistenceunit."progettoswam-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war#production": javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: production] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory

20:50:37,755 INFO  [org.jboss.as.repository] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) WFLYDR0002: Content removed from location C:\Users\Andrea\Documents\Unifi\swam\Application Server\wildfly-14.0.1.Final\standalone\data\content\4d\2d1edadf3cd63b4636859320b2476b1c1076e8\content
```

Persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">

    <persistence-unit name="production">
        <jta-data-source>hermesDS</jta-data-source> 

        <class>it.unifi.ing.stlab.model.user.User</class>
        <class>it.unifi.ing.stlab.model.request.Request</class>

        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false"/>
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.use_sql_comments" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.default_batch_fetch_size" value="16" />
            <property name="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size" value="100" />
            <property name="hibernate.order_inserts" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.order_updates" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings" value="true" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Edit:

tempro-ds.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<datasources xmlns="http://www.jboss.org/ironjacamar/schema"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.jboss.org/ironjacamar/schema
        http://docs.jboss.org/ironjacamar/schema/datasources_1_0.xsd">

    <datasource jndi-name="temproDS" enabled="true" use-java-context="true" pool-name="MySQLDS">
        <connection-url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/progettoswam?useSSL=false</connection-url>
        <driver>mysql</driver>
        <security>
            <user-name>root</user-name>
            <password>root</password>
        </security>
    </datasource>

</datasources>
```

[Credential are correct](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GDZ5n.png)

Comment: It looks like something is wrong with your data source. Can you post your data source configuration?

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins , i've added the data source. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getServerCharset(ConnectionImpl.java:2997)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendConnectionAttributes(MysqlIO.java:1934)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.proceedHandshakeWithPluggableAuthentication(MysqlIO.java:1863)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1226)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2253)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2284)
    ... 44 more
```

Looks like the Client you use isn't matching with the server. Check the server version and update the client driver in your pom or dependencies.

Comment: I've **updated the connector from 5.1.40 to 5.1.44** and now it works!
Thanks for the help!

Comment: Welcome! could you please upvote the answer and close !